# Updating AVRO files in GCS using data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, avro

I'm working on a POC to extract data from an API and load new/updated records to AVRO file present in GCS, I also want to delete the record that comes with a deleted flag, from the AVRO file.

What would be a feasible approach to implement this using dataflow, are there any resources that I can refer to for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't update file in GCS. You can only READ, WRITE and DELETE. If you have to change 1 byte in the file, you need to download the file, make the change and upload it again.

You can keep versions in GCS, but each BLOB is unique and can be changed.

---

Anyway, you can do that with dataflow, but keep in mind that you need 2 inputs:

1. The data to update
2. The file stored in GCS (that you have to read and to process also with dataflow)

At the end, you need to write the new file in GCS, with the data stored in dataflow.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try reading and then deleting the file before uploading it back with updated content

Comment: If you write the file with the same name and you haven't the versioning activated on the bucket, you don't need to delete it, the previous file will be override.